How to extract individual key,values from string type dataframe column in pyspark
dataframe schema is as follows
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address_info: string (nullable = true)

sample contents or address_info column is as below
{original_email=test@sparp.org, fqdn=sparp.org, domain=sharp, host=sharp.org, subdomain=, alias=, addr=test, tld=org, normalized_email=test@sharp.org}

Tried to convert to json by using from_json and using the custom schema to match the address_info, but no luck.
desired output of dataframe is as follows :
name original_email   fqdn        domain
XXX  test@sparp.org   sparp.org   sharp

Tried to convert string type column to json by using from_json by using the custom schema to match the address_info, but no luck.
Expected output of dataframe :
name original_email   fqdn        domain
XXX  test@sparp.org   sparp.org   sharp


The solution provided in the following links worked :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498349/how-to-extract-string-type-dictionary-using-python-pyspark
